# BufferedReader error in Fibonacci sequence in Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, readline

I am new to Java, coming from a C background. While trying to implement a Fibonacci Sequence,I received the following error:

> ```
>  error: cannot find symbol
>     n = Integer.parseInt(br.readline());
>                            ^
>  symbol:   method readline()
>  location: variable br of type BufferedReader
> ```

The program is as follows :

```
import java.io.*;

public class fibonacci
{
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
    int n;
    InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(read);

    System.out.println("enter the value of n");
    n = Integer.parseInt(br.readline());

int fib[];
    fib[1]=1;
    fib[2]=1;
    for(int i=3; i<=n; i++)
    {
        fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2] ;
    }

    System.out.println("the"+n+"th fibonacci term is "+fib[n]);
}
}
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Compilation errors have nothing to do with Fibonacci sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is case sensitive

```
n = Integer.parseInt(br.readline());
                            ^
```

should be

```
n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it should be `readLine` instead of `readline`. Please keep in mind that JAVA is case-sensistive. And please use the IDE, it will catch such mistakes even before compilation.